# Does it matter where I get PhD degree from if I want an academic career in the US?

Tags: career-path

I am an EU citizen who is going to apply to PhD Physics programs soon. My ultimate goal is to become a university professor. In considering which university I should attend for PhD, factors such as tuition & program differences don't matter to me. What matters is that I don't feel like doing (nor do I agree with) the GRE (which would require a significant preparation), thus applying to PhD programs in the US might be out of the picture for me. However, the question pertains that if I want an academic career (ultimately, a professor position) in the US in the future, does it matter from which university I get my PhD degree?

Note: I do not care about a uni's rank or status. What I care about is whether the uni's location (different country) will affect where I can get jobs later on...

PS: On a separate matter, I've heard that PhD graduates in the US can obtain academic jobs without going through postdocs, is that true? If so, what does it take do achieve that?

Comment: In answer to your non-postdoc question to tenure track sidebar, yes, it is possible in some fields (such as philosophy), but in other fields I gather 1 to 2 postdocs is the norm. But it's almost entirely field dependent (and then luck getting a TT without having to find something else).

Comment: The separate matter should be asked in a separate question. Regarding the main question: Maybe focus on the aspect of whether there is an advantage of getting your PhD from a university in the same system as you want to get a faculty position at? Other aspects have already been covered in the quesiton linked by virmaior.

Comment: I don't know that I agree that this is a duplicate of that question, since that question concerns rank and OP explicitly states that they don't care about rank, but rather that they care about country. However, I know that this question has been addressed here -- but I'm unable to find the answer in question.